# Chapter 5, Section 5 Exercise 3 is false of James Dugundji Topology

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

> Let $X$ be a connected no singleton set in $(Y,\tau_{cof})$ with $Y$ infinite. Show that $X$ is totally pathwise disconnected. (By definition, $X$ is totally pathwise disconnected if the only continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ are the constant maps.)

$X$ is infinite, because the connected sets in the cofinite topology are the singletons and the infinite sets when $Y$ is infinite.

I've been trying to prove this exercise. But i think that a counterexample could be the following function:

$\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$

$\phi(x)=x$

And $\phi$ is continuous because $\tau_{cof}\subseteq\tau_u$ where $\tau_u$ is the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, your example is correct. In fact, any injective function from $[0,1]$ into the cofinite topology is continuous. The theorem would hold for countable $Y$. It's an interesting question, for which cardinalities strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ this is true, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285780/are-the-sierpi%c5%84ski-cardinal-acute-mathfrak-n-and-its-measure-modification)